# git new branch from commit doesn't checkout the code properly

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a repo where my master has many commits... i want to create a new fresh branch from the first commit (the original code) so i do as follows:

`git checkout -b mybranch 4589D6a09505837ec03b`

where `4589D6a09505837ec03b` is the first commit id... everything seems ok and now i'm at `mybranch`. But I look at the code and it's exactly the same thing as my `master`! i even run my server from the new checkedout branch and it looks the same as `master`. Maybe there's something wrong with the id.. how can i ask github to pull the first ever commit from master?

**EDITED:** can I do this from a remote repo's master branch instead? just branch that code into my local repo. I don't want to recreate a repo for it.

Comment: do a `git diff` between that commit and master to see if there was even a difference.

Comment: there's one difference, not huge tho... that can't be right.. any way i can specify the first id? maybe the id isn't right but that's the first id that shows when i do a git log

Comment: When you say the first ID that shows in `git log`, what do you mean? Are you aware that by default log shows commits in reverse order so that the commit at the top of the list will be the most recent one?

Comment: Yeah i know.. i meant the first from the oldest one, i should have been more clear. It's the right id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is:

```
git checkout 4589D6a09505837ec03b
git checkout -b mybranch
```

<strike>From the [man page on git checkout](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html), when you put the commit id where you're putting it, what you're doing is telling git where to *start* the repository from, not where to end it, which is what I think you're wanting to do. (If I'm wrong on my assumption there, let me know.)</strike>

Edit: These commands have the same behavior as the original question.

Comment: Those two commands have the same effect as the single command in the question.  Your first command points HEAD at the specified commit, then the second creates a branch pointing to HEAD and checks it out.  The command in the question would create the new branch pointing to the specified commit and check it out.

Comment: Thanks Ben, yes that seem to have different code thanks, i'm however finding that the first commit is not good enough.. how can i check out a new branch from a remote repository master instead? the only way i've found so far is by cloning the repo.. which i don't want to do because i don't want to have to run db and seed and blah blah

Comment: @qqx: No, the effect is different. The single command in the question creates a branch that *starts* at commit `4589D6a09505837ec03b` and goes to the current HEAD. This pair of commands creates a branch that *ends* at commit `4589D6a09505837ec03b`.

Comment: @user1994202: I'm not understanding your question. What's this db and seed you have to run? Can you use your previous command to create a checkout starting from an earlier commit, using the remote repository as a beginning?

Comment: I did but I think that commit is not good enough, i'll need to grab it from the remote repo's master branch into a new branch. If i were to clone it (like i did originaly) i'll have to create another folder, clone it there, run rake db, run seed, setup the environment again which i think it's overkill.

Comment: @BenHocking No, your 2 commands are the same as the single command from the question.  git doesn't even have a concept of where a branch starts, only the commit which is currently at the tip of the branch.

Comment: OK nevermind i did what Ben suggested and used the commit of the remote repository's master branch.. it seems to have worked.. thanks for all your help.

Comment: @qqx: You are correct. I was basing it off what the man page said and evidently I misunderstood it. I just tested it, and they do in fact exhibit the same behavior.